# How to make type-stable function that selects subset of data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

I am writing a very basic function that detects columns with a particular name and then returns the table excluding those columns. I am not sure how what's the most concise way to make this function type-stable wherein it accepts either data.frames or data.tables and spits out the result table in the same class it came in.

So for example, my usual workflow is to use data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(names = sample(c("Ruby","Fire","Azure","Green"), 10, replace = T), age = 10:19, phone = 123456:123465)
df <- data.frame(names = sample(c("Ruby","Fire","Azure","Green"), 10, replace = T), age = 10:19, phone = 123456:123465)
detach("package:data.table")

removeAge <- function(db){
    ageCols <- grepl("age",names(db))
    db <- db[, !ageCols]
    return(db)
}

removeAge(df) # returns data.frame with age column removed
removeAge(dt) # returns vector of logical T,F,T
```

How can I make the `removeAge` function in my example be agnostic of whether the input table is a data.frame or data.table? This example will also help me learn for more complex functions. I assume one way is to check whether the input table class and convert to data.frame, but for large tables I am guessing this would be computationally expensive.

Would love to learn what good practice in this situation is.

Thanks!

Comment: Then my function would not work if the table passed into the function was not a data.table and the R sessions did not have data.table package loaded. Is it possible to write a line/two of code that subsets columns for either data.frame or data.table inputs

Comment: Edit: Actually, on just replacing that line I get a logic vector for both.

Comment: True, it was my first thought. See my answer for a solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to change the function to:

```
removeAge <- function(db){
  ageCols <- grepl('age', names(db))
  db <- as.data.frame(db)[, !ageCols]
  return(db)
}
```

Now using either `removeAge(df)` or `removeAge(dt)` give the intended result:

> ```
> > removeAge(df) 
>    names  phone
> 1   Ruby 123456
> 2  Azure 123457
> 3   Ruby 123458
> 4   Ruby 123459
> 5   Fire 123460
> 6  Azure 123461
> 7  Green 123462
> 8   Ruby 123463
> 9  Green 123464
> 10 Azure 123465
>
> > removeAge(dt)
>    names  phone
> 1  Azure 123456
> 2   Fire 123457
> 3  Green 123458
> 4  Azure 123459
> 5   Fire 123460
> 6  Green 123461
> 7  Azure 123462
> 8  Green 123463
> 9   Fire 123464
> 10 Azure 123465
> ```

---

To use `data.table`-like subsetting, you could also adapt your function to:

```
removeAge <- function(db){
  nonAgeCols <- setdiff(names(db), 'age')
  db <- setDT(db)[, ..nonAgeCols]
  return(db)
}
```

---

If you want to retain the class of the `data.table` or the `data.frame`, then you could change your function to:

```
removeAge <- function(db) {
  if (any(class(db) == 'data.table')) {
    nonAgeCols <- setdiff(names(db), 'age')
    db <- setDT(db)[, ..nonAgeCols]
    return(db)
  } else {
    ageCols <- grepl("age",names(db))
    db <- db[, !ageCols]
    return(db)
  }
}
```

which return a `data.table` of a `data.frame` depending on the class of the input:

> ```
> > class(removeAge(df))
> [1] "data.frame"
> > class(removeAge(dt))
> [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> ```

Comment: @SehjKashyap [Here you can find more on the `..`-notation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1). It was introduced last year.

Comment: Thanks so much Jaap. This is really helpful. I did realize that both of your solutions change the class of the input table into one specific class. Am I not understanding? I was hoping that data.frame --> function --> data.frame, while data.table --> function --> data.table, or generally for any class of table, it returns the input table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Another thing I realized is that if this were a function that were loaded via a library instead of the source function, then it would have no problem using the data.frame lingo on a data.table because data.tables themselves are compatible with data.frame functions. On the other hand, if this is loaded via source, then data.frame lingo does not work. What explains the difference in behavior between the source vs. library loading of the same function?

Comment: Your use of setDT also sent on a chase to figure out what that was. Looks like a wonderful function that I can use in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @SehjKashyap If you use `source(your_R_file.R)` to load you function, make to include `library(data.table)` inside that file as well.